# How to put contents on the same page as a title of a paper

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using this format for my chapters

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstcol}
\makeatletter
\def\LigneVerticale{\vrule height 1.5cm depth 0.9cm\hspace{0.1cm}\relax}
\def\LignesVerticales{%
  \let\LV\LigneVerticale\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV}
\def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre#1{%
  \rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
  \rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\white #1}\hss}}%
  \vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}
\def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffres#1{{%
  \color{white}%
  \rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
  %\rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\color{black}#1}\hss}}%
  %\vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}}
  \hspace{-0.65cm}
  }}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    \vspace*{-20pt}
    \hbox{%
    \huge\bfseries
    \LignesVerticales
    \hspace{-0.62cm}%
    \GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre{\thechapter}
    \hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
    }\par\vskip 0.5cm}
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{
         \vspace*{-20pt}
    \hbox{%
    \huge\bfseries
    \LignesVerticales
    \hspace{-0.62cm}%
    \GrosCarreAvecUnChiffres{\thechapter}
    \hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
    }\par\vskip 0.5cm}
\makeatother
```

The contents is always on a new page, but i would like to have it under the title on the first page. Anyone knows how to make it?

Comment: I suspect something like `\let\cleardoublepage\relax` etc. just before `\tableofcontents`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Answer? :-p

Comment: @ChristianHupfer or something else?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I'll think about it later on

Comment: @Johannes_B: Answered finally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ToC on the title page in a report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45861/toc-on-the-title-page-in-a-report)

Answer (score 4):

This is a guess only (since no MWE was given): Using the `book` class and patching `\tableofcontents` and `\@maketitle` slightly to remove the `\newpage` or `\cleardoublepage` usage.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\xpretocmd{\tableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup\let\cleardoublepage\relax
}{}{}

\xapptocmd{\tableofcontents}{%
  \endgroup%
}{}{}

\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\newpage\null}{}{}{}
}
\makeatother

\title{Theory of Brontosaurs}
\author{Ann Elk}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\def\LigneVerticale{\vrule height 1.5cm depth 0.9cm\hspace{0.1cm}\relax}
\def\LignesVerticales{%
  \let\LV\LigneVerticale\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV}
\def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre#1{%
  \rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
  \rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\white #1}\hss}}%
  \vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}
\def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffres#1{{%
  \color{white}%
  \rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
  %\rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\color{black}#1}\hss}}%
  %\vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}}
  \hspace{-0.65cm}
  }}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    \vspace*{-20pt}
    \hbox{%
    \huge\bfseries
    \LignesVerticales
    \hspace{-0.62cm}%
    \GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre{\thechapter}
    \hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
    }\par\vskip 0.5cm}
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{
         \vspace*{-20pt}
    \hbox{%
    \huge\bfseries
    \LignesVerticales
    \hspace{-0.62cm}%
    \GrosCarreAvecUnChiffres{\thechapter}
    \hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
    }\par\vskip 0.5cm}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]