# Combine title page and contents on one page

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, page-numbering

Is it possible to have the Table of Contents follow immediately after the Title Page in  `\documentclass{book}`?

In other words: print the `\title{}` and `\author{}` *(and preferably not the `\date{}`)*, and right below that on the same page, the `\tableofcontents` -- without a page break, and without a page number.

Bonus points if

- (a) the text content, i.e., Chapter One, begins on page 3, since chapters should begin on odd pages;
- and  (b) Page two can optionally include copyright notice, etc., but if not there should be no printing on that page at all.

MWE is below. Sorry it isn't very minimal. *(Please be gentle. I'm having a hard time wrestling LaTeX to do what I want.)*

```
\documentclass[notitlepage,draft]{book}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[fontsize=10pt,baseline=12pt]{grid} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\usepackage[top=2cm, left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry} 
\setmainfont{Alegreya}  % yes, you can print in non-default fonts!
\title{This Is The Title\\of the\\Adequate Book of \LaTeX}
\author{MacIntyre W. Hovermale, Jr., Esq.}
\usepackage{titling}  % remove date and spacing around date:
\predate{}
\date{}
\postdate{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  %% controls headers/footers, page numbers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{TEST~~~EVEN~~~PAGE~~~HEADER}
\fancyhead[CO]{\chaptername} 
\usepackage[ragged,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktoc=all]{hyperref}  %% make contents entries clickable 

\begin{document}

\maketitle 
 
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}  %% no header on blank left page; will clearing get TOC to start immediately? ans: no, it just restores lopsided header on blank p. 2.

\tableofcontents

%%%%% CHAPTER ONE %%%%%
\chapter*{chapter one} 
\label{ch:Chapter_One}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Chapter one}  %% add unnumbered chap. to TOC
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution presented in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45863/134144 should also work if you use the `book` class.

Comment: you could even throw in a `\section*{\contentsname}`

Comment: why not create your own titlepage with a toc rather than relying on `maketitle`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I could not get them to work, and I am throwing in the towel on this one. I have other formatting and presentation challenges in this document that are more important to me. I am humbled by those who can make wonderful, complex LaTeX documents, but unfortunately I am not one of them. My last dip into the LaTeX pool was several years ago, and I ended up just going back to LibreOffice Writer. This time I am committed to a final product done in LaTeX, but it just isn't going to be exactly like I imagined.