# Formatting revtex 4 title page

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titles, revtex, abstract

This code makes contents table appear above title and abstract.
I want both on same page.
Please help.

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,dvipsnames] {revtex4-1}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%(and other packages relevant to my document)
\begin{document}
\title{Radiotherapy Rotation}
\author{Saoirse Conroy}
\date{Feb 2023}
\begin{abstract}
\centering
Please see ``references" for note to which competency/ies a section is fulfilling, any academic references or acknowledgements will be written in the text where appropriate instead.
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\maketitle
\pagebreak
```

Comment: Found a workable soultion : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/555308/290378

Answer (score 1):

The title and abstract are typeset at the point of `\maketitle`, not when the relevant macros are used, so it is neccessary for `\tablecontents` to follow `\maketitle`.

With the more recent [`revtex4-2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex) this is all that is required

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,dvipsnames] {revtex4-2}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%(and other packages relevant to my document)
\begin{document}
\title{Radiotherapy Rotation}
\author{Author}
\date{Feb 2023}
\begin{abstract}
\centering
Please see ``references" for note to which competency/ies a section is fulfilling, any academic references or acknowledgements will be written in the text where appropriate instead.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\end{document}
```

With [`revtex4-1`](https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1), the class option `notitlepage` is also required.

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,dvipsnames,notitlepage] {revtex4-1}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%(and other packages relevant to my document)
\begin{document}
\title{Radiotherapy Rotation}
\author{Author}
\date{Feb 2023}
\begin{abstract}
\centering
Please see ``references" for note to which competency/ies a section is fulfilling, any academic references or acknowledgements will be written in the text where appropriate instead.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,dvipsnames,notitlepage] {revtex4-1}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\toccontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Radiotherapy Rotation}
\author{Saoirse Conroy}
\date{Feb 2023}
\begin{abstract}
\centering
Please see ``references" for note to which competency/ies a section is fulfilling, any academic references or acknowledgements will be written in the text where appropriate instead.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\toccontents

\pagebreak
```